# Using TPL parallel work inside an async wcf service method

Tags: wcf, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have one doubt. I implemented my wcf 4.0 service method as shown below.

```
    IAsyncResult BeginGetData(string userid, AsyncCallback cb, object asyncState)
    {
       // Here i want to call 2 different methods simultaneously of another class

       // string result1 = classA.Method1(userid);
       // string result2 = classA.Method2(userid);        

    }
```

How I can call 2 methods simultaneously and both result values send back to client in the same return method ? Can we do it using TPL ? In TPL, if we use Task.ContinueWith, it will run sequentially. Is there any way that run those 2 methods parallely and return the 2 results through the EndGetData method ? If Method1 is completing first, then it should wait for Method2 to complete. Or another way is to fireback each method result as and when they completed. Is this possible ? Please help and guide me.

Comment: Are those methods asynchronous? Because they don't look that way. In that case, there is not much you're going to gain from making your method asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the intracacies of using WCF to do all of this for you. However, here you can just use Task Parallel Library's (TPL) [`ContinueWhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321473.aspx) keyword:

An example of its usage is

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("X"));
Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Y"));
```

this fires the two task off concurrently on two seperate background thread-pool threads. You can then wait for both to finish using

```
var continuation = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
    new[] { task1, task2 }, tasks => Console.WriteLine("Done!"));
```

Or here, you could also use the `WhenAll` task combinator and write

```
var continuation = Task.WhenAll(task1, task2)
    .ContinueWith(ant => Console.Writeline("Done!"));
```

Example in your case of returning data from the tasks:

```
Task<int> task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => 
    { 
        return SomeSerialMethodReturningInt32A(); 
    });
Task<int> task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => 
    { 
        return SomeSerialMethodReturningInt32B(); 
    });
```

then in the continuation (what ever method of continuation you choose), you can query the results (and remember to observe your [`AggregateException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx)s) as follows

```
var continuation = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
    new[] { task1, task2 }, tasks => 
        { 
            int i = task1.Result;
            int j = task2.Result;
            // Neglecting exception handling.
        });
```

See [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-1-of-n) for a great introduction to TPL.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Calling `StartNew()` twice doesn't guarantee the two `Task`s will execute on different threads. If the first one finishes quickly, the second one may be executed on the same thread. Also, `WhenAll()` is available only in .Net 4.5; and if you have that, you might as well use `await`.

Comment: He did not mention Framework version. However, here I desagree. I would not use await here. The structure of the code when using `ContinueWhenAll` is 'nicer' IMO. It does not hide anything and provides clarity.

Comment: I agree with the 'it may not spawn a new thread'. I have made the appropriate edit...

Comment: @Killercam thanks for the help. can we use Parallel invoke ? if possible. Please help.

Comment: The two `Task`s should indeed have a `Result` property. I have set up a console application that does exactly what I have shown.

Comment: There is no need to use the `Parrallel` class here. This wouuld be a large over complication IMO.

Comment: @Killercam yes there is. i forgot to use task<string>. sorry for my mistakes. btw, is there anyway that we can do the 2 tasks in parallel ? pls help.

Comment: If they are 'long running' two threads will be spawned, one for each `Task`. in this case they will be concurrent (or 'parallel', but not in the stricttest sense of the word). As I have said there is no need for parallelisation here...

Comment: thanks for the helps. I dont have WhenAll, instead can i use ContinueWhenAll ?

Comment: Yes, as i have said the two methods produce the same result.